# Using a Regular Expressions as a conditional loop (until)

Tags: ruby, regex, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use a regular expression as a condition inside (until) loop.
basically, It's for entering numeric password..

I tried this code

```
   print "Password: "
   x = gets.chomp.to_i
   until (/^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === "#{x}") == "true"
      print "Only numbers allowed, Password: "
      x = gets.chomp.to_i
   end
```

but unfortunately it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the "[Ruby]" from the title, it's enough to have it in the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't compare to the string `"true"`. In fact in Ruby you barely ever should need to explicitly compare to `true` or `false`, since that's what boolean expressions evaluate to. Also note that `to_i` probably does not do what you expect:

```
"adsfasf34".to_i #=> 0
"1adsfasf34".to_i #=> 1
```

What you can do is something like this:

```
print "Password: "
until (x = gets.chomp) =~ /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/
  print "Only numbers allowed, Password: "
end
x = x.to_i
```

Comment: You were faster and more concise, I'll delete :)

Comment: I'd like to ask, Is the condition now means "keep printing until X **matched the pattern**.. etc." in spoken english?

Comment: Yes, the loop would read "until x (which you get with gets.chomp) matches (=~) the regular expression (/.../) print the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this doesn't work. `===` ("triqual") is the equivalent "Is of the same class as". So what you are doing there is asking Ruby if

```
 (a class of this regex is the same as the class of the string) equals string "true"
```

The inner comparison in this case is botched and would never work to begin with (Regexp and a string are never of the same class anyway), the outer one would never work either (Ruby has no magic string constants like ECMAscript's `undefined`).

For conditionals in Ruby it's handy to remember this: any expression evaluating to anything else than `nil` or `false` will be true! so the regular expression match operator will do just fine (it returns `nil` when no matches are found, which is what you are looking for, and the offset at which the match is when found - and any integer in Ruby is "trueish", even 0).

So indeed,

```
print "Password: "
x = gets.chomp

until /^[\d]+$/ =~ x
  print "Only numbers allowed, Password: "
  x = gets.chomp
end

pw =x.to_i
```

Comment: so that's mean any condition in ruby is achieved while it's true, even if it's not in a equality case.. right?   
Thanks a lot for these valuable information. especially for a 24 h old ruby developer like me..